# How do I write System.out.println() with just ctrl + space in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I used to be able to write System.out.println() with just ctrl+space. Now I have to choose the proposal and press enter. So it's ctrl+space and enter now. It's just an extra key but pretty annoying.

I've tried restoring the preferences to default, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Preferences -> java -> editor -> content assist -> check "insert single proposals automatically" -> content assist -> advanced -> in the top table, uncheck everything except "template proposals"

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75084288/how-do-i-write-system-out-println-with-just-ctrl-space-in-eclipse#comment132501419_75084288) by [XtremeBaumer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7109162/xtremebaumer):

Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist

- *Check "Insert single proposals automatically"*

Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced

- *In the top table, uncheck everything except "Template Proposals"*

Verified in Eclipse for Java Developers, Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)